# for /f loop to call powershell with arguments not working

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to execute the following command from a Windows batch script.

```bash
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell.exe -File ".\GetValues1.ps1 USB"') do set "$ExternalDrive=%%a"
```

This returns the following value.

```
"External Drive Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows"
```

The external drive is from my `echo`, the rest is what returns in the variable.

However, if I run this same line withhout passing an argument:

```bash
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell.exe -File ".\GetValues1.ps1"') do set "$ExternalDrive=%%a"
```

I receive a valid response back from the PowerShell script.

```
"External Drive Error: FIP Not Found"
```

The PowerShell script will default to which function to run if no values are passed.

I have tried enclosing the argument to be passed with `'`, but I receive the same error.  I also tried enclosing the argument in `"`, but that does the same thing too.

Sugestions please?

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: `'powershell.exe -File ".\GetValues1.ps1 USB"'` -> `'powershell.exe -File ".\GetValues1.ps1" USB'` - the script file passed to `-File` and its arguments must be passed as separate arguments. See the documentation of [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI.

Comment: Time to switch to powershell.

Comment: It is also common to use `-NoLogo -NoProfile` on PowerShell invocations. Onward to PowerShell Core. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you. I am sorry for the improperly formatted question.  And thank you for the answer.   I feel stupid for missing that.  When i see it, it just makes sense.  Marked you up for your answer.  again, thank you.  Dan

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @OldAndRetired. While up-voting _comments_ is also helpful, up-voting and especially [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/248777) _answers_ is even more so, so I encourage you to revisit your previous questions and accept / up-vote answers there, if appropriate.